# Connect "WordPress Media Gallery " to a FTP directory

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I connect my WordPress media gallery directly to a FTP server?

I have tones of pictures (like gigabytes) and I can't host it on my WordPress host, then I bought a download server (e.g `files.example.com`).

I need that when an admin uploads a new picture for a gallery, the picture upload into the FTP server not on current server. How to do that?

And I don't know how to use my pictures(`files.mywordpress.com/pictures/`) in WordPress media gallery, as I know, WP does not have any plugin to import just links into the media gallery. How to make pictures show just by a link on hosted download server not on WordPress host?

Comment: im about to write a plugin about it , PLEASE ! if anyone knows anything, let me know !

Comment: I tried to make sense of your question, so future readers can understand it better. Feel free to adjust anything that I got bad, but please try to keep the good formatting and proper words capitalisation. I don't know the answer and to study the issue I would had to do some research at [wordpress.se], unfortunately I spent my time editing the Question ;) - If you find resources in your research and update the Q, ping me and I'll take a look. Good luck!

Comment: @brasofilo , i appreciate, now its clear what i want :), thanks

Comment: Any updates? It would be great to know how to have WordPress' media gallery use images that are URL based rather than actually uploaded into the gallery.